# traffic density visualization in Python

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization

I have a csv file with traffic density data per road segment of a certain high way, measured in Annual average daily traffic (AADT). Now I want to visualize this data.

Since I have the locations (lat and lon) of the road segments, my idea is to create lines between these points and give it a color which relates to the AADT value. So suppose, road segments / lines with high AADT are marked red and low AADT are marked green.

Which package should I use for this visualization?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without any information about the structure of the data.
Is it just points? Is it a shapefile? Probably you should start with geopandas....

Comment: Actually every row decribes one road segment: one collumn of this row descbibes the longitude, one the lattitude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/) just as displayed in the link.